# Dialog of proxy authentication when open Android studio

Tags: android-studio, proxy

I opened my Android Studio and suddenly I got a proxy authentication window
I tried to enter my computer login information but the window pops up again
Does anyone know why this is and how to solve it? Thanks

[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcowU.png)

I have tried to restart the PC but no success